# populating spinner using JSON

Tags: android, json

I'm facing a problem with populating spinner with json data. The code that i used does not return anything. The code is as follows

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    primaryid=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 

    AsyncHttpClient usercheck=new AsyncHttpClient();
    usercheck.get("URL", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
        public void onSuccess(String response){
            try {
                JSONObject obj3 = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray3 = obj3.getJSONArray("PopulateSuppliersList");
                 name=obj3.getJSONArray("name");
                int length3 = jsonArray3.length();
                  List<String> listContents3 = new ArrayList<String>(length3);
                  for (int i = 0; i < length3; i++)
                  {
                      JSONObject user3 = jsonArray3.getJSONObject(i);
                      if(user3.getInt("ID")>=5){
                      listContents3.add(user3.getString("SUPPLIER_NAME"));}
                      }
                      primaryid = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                      primaryid.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, listContents3));
                  }


             catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: show JSON string which getting from server response

Comment: why you are creating the adapter in the loop? and it seems you already have done referencing the "primaryid" spinner. but these are not the problems. Still it should be okay to see some data in the spinner. you should show the JSON string in your question.  And before setting the adapter try to print the listContents3 list just for debugging purpose.

Comment: json string cannot be disclosed.it is give by a company

Comment: is there any changes to be done to the code?

Comment: this is the REST method to be used method PopulateSuppliersList?iActivationStatusID={iActivationStatusID} for populating the spinner

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have to do with method synchronicity. You're sending an Async request (which you don't know when will return) in your OnCreate. This means you are trying to update your UI thread after OnCreate has already finished. You must update the UI in some Method that connects with the UI thread, like OnPostExecute in AsyncTask or OnFinished in the class you are using AsyncHttpResponseHandler.